# React State becomes undefined when testing onChange handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test some React/Redux code by checking the value of state after the value of a Textfield is changed.

I tried setting the .value of the input, but that does nothing.
Simulating the onChange event causes the state field that I am trying to change (query) to become undefined.

I've gone through several similar posts on this issue but can't seem to figure it out.

```
    <TextField
      label="Search Term"
      styles={{ root: { width: 200 } }}
      id="query"
      placeholder="Query"
      onChange={(_,v) => this.setState({ query: v })}
    />
```

Testing file

```
    const wrapper = shallow(<Dataset/>);
    wrapper.find(TextField).at(1).value = "20"; //does nothing
    wrapper.find(TextField).at(1).simulate('change', 20); //causes state.query to become undefined
    wrapper.find(PrimaryButton).at(0).simulate('click');
    wrapper.update();
    expect(wrapper.state('query')).toEqual(20);
```

I'm new to React testing, so any advice in what direction I should take is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v` is undefined, use `_` instead. And in test file maybe you need to find at 0 and not at 1?

Comment: I'm sure that the index(1) in the test file is correct, but I'm confused by what you mean about undefined? The onChange function works fine outside of testing

Comment: That fixed it btw, I'm just confused on why it fixed it.

Comment: Actually it only fixes the test, it fails in production now :(